# Join values from array as keys to values from another array (JOLT)

Tags: json, jolt

From this JSON below:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "ids":[
         95445875
      ],
      "group": "day",
      "dimensions":[
         "ym:s:date",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMSource",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMMedium",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMCampaign",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMContent",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMTerm"
      ],
      "metrics":[
         "ym:s:goal315094773visits",
         "ym:s:goal318656867visits"
      ]
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-12"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka"
            },
            {
               "name":"SITE"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_nov23"
            },
            {
               "name":"button"
            },
            {
               "name":"click"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            64.0,
            2.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-13"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka"
            },
            {
               "name":"SITE"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_nov23"
            },
            {
               "name":"button"
            },
            {
               "name":"click"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            13.0,
            0.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-13"
            },
            {
               "name":"Yandex"
            },
            {
               "name":"SEM"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23"
            },
            {
               "name":"TGB"
            },
            {
               "name":"shop"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            5.0,
            4.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-12"
            },
            {
               "name":"Yandex"
            },
            {
               "name":"SEM"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23"
            },
            {
               "name":"TGB"
            },
            {
               "name":"shop"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            3.0,
            0.0
         ]
      }
   ],
   "total_rows":4
}
```

I expect to get this result:

```json
[
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":64.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":2.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":13.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":0.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":5.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":4.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":3.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":0.0
   }
]
```

**Explanation**

From souce JSON I need:

- id from `query.ids` array and call new property `counter_id`
- compare and join values from array `query.dimensions` and values from array `data.dimensions`, but give them new names. Values from `query.dimensions` should be property names for values from `data.dimensions` (we need this to keep right order). After this I want to change these names: `ym:s:date` should be `date_of_visit`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMSource` should be `utm_source`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMMedium` to `utm_medium`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMCampaign` to `utm_campaign`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMContent` to `utm_content`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMTerm` to `utm_term`.
- compare and join values from `query.metrics` with values from array `data.metrics`. But each element from array `query.metrics`. f.e. `ym:s:goal315094773visits` should be written as `goal_id`: 315094773 (we need value between goal....visits). And value from `data.metrics` should be written as `conversions`.

So I expect to get result JSON like above presented.

I hard worked with it and got this JOLT config, but it doesn't even work.
My knowledge is definetely not enough(

[image: JOLT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten by the following transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": { // loop through all the "data"
        "*": { // indexes of the "data"
          "metrics": { // loop through all the "metrics"
            "*": { // indexes of the "metrics"
              "@4,query.ids[0]": "&3_&.counter_id",
              "@2,dimensions[0].name": "&3_&.date_of_visit",
              "@2,dimensions[1].name": "&3_&.utm_source",
              "@2,dimensions[2].name": "&3_&.utm_medium",
              "@2,dimensions[3].name": "&3_&.utm_campaign",
              "@2,dimensions[4].name": "&3_&.utm_content",
              "@2,dimensions[5].name": "&3_&.utm_term",
              "@4,query.metrics[&]": {
                "*goal*visits": {
                  "$(0,2)": "&5_&2.goal_id" // extract the value of 2nd replacement of asterisks from the key just after going upper (0th)level
                }
              },
              "@": "&3_&.conversions" // the values of the "metrics"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You're an insane JOLT master!

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is dynamic regardless of how many query dimensions you have, or how many data metrics you have. The only condition is the query dimension order coincides with the data dimension order to match each value with its field based on that order:

```json
[
  {
    //prepare fields names in query dimensions by
    //concat utm_ prefix to them changing to lowercase
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "query": {
        "dimensions": {
          "*": "=concat('utm_',@(0))"
        },
        "dimensionJoin": "=join(',',@(1,dimensions))",
        "dimensionsLowercase": "=toLower(@(1,dimensionJoin))",
        "fields": "=split('[,]',@(1,dimensionsLowercase))"
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    //extract query metrics values for global ids
    // apply each data metric value to the above dimension, this 
    // will produce a data object of 4 records where each record
    // contains 2 dimensions for each metric
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "query": {
        "metrics": {
          "*": {
            "ym:s:goal*visits": {
              "$(0,1)": "query.metrics[&2]"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "metrics": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,dimensions)": "data[&3].[&1].dimensions",
              "@": "data[&3].[&1].conversions"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
 ,
  {
    // flatten the data nested arrays above utilizing
    // unique index combination of parent-child arrays
    // which we can group each record fields under
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "dimensions": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&4_&3.@(6,query.fields.[&1])"
              }
            },
            "conversions": "&2_&1.&",
            "@(3,query.ids[0])": "&2_&1.counter_id",
            "@(3,query.metrics[&1])": "&2_&1.goal_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
  ,
  {
    // remove unique index grouping and bucket all
    // 8 records into one parent array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
    }
   ,
  {
    //rename fields accordingly
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*date":"[&1].date_of_visit",
        "*ym:s:lastsignutm*": "[&1].&(0,1)&(0,2)",
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
    } /**/
]
```